# IEEE format for stating authors

Tags: ieeetran

For IEEE authors, what is the difference between `\IEEEauthorblockN` and `\IEEEauthorblockA`? Is there more than these?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro `\IEEEauthorblockN` should be used to state the **n**ames of the authors, and the macro `\IEEEauthorblockA` should be used to state the authors' **a**ffiliations. Both macros should be used inside an `\author{...}` directive.

One should use the `\IEEEauthorblockN` and `\IEEEauthorblockA` macros mainly if the document is being prepared for a conference, in which case one would write

```
\documentclass[conference,<other options>]{IEEEtran}
```

Here's a usage example straight out of the user guide of the `IEEEtran` package:

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}
\IEEEauthorblockA{School of Electrical and\\
Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology\\
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250}}
```